# Display cross-block summary formula in a report chart

Tags: joined-reports, report-chart

I have a joined report with two blocks.  I have a cross-block summary formula that produces a number value at the bottom of the report correctly.  I want to display this number in a metric chart on the report.  However, the metric chart option is not available & I can't seem to get the cross-block summary formula to show on any of the reports.  As soon as I try to use it as one of the measurements, I receive a message indicating that 0 results are available.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. If anyone comes across this and has an answer, please update the post!